# Como pegar a maior palavra de uma string em Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Olá, gostaria de saber como pego a maior palavra dessa string abaixo:

```
var string = "Bom dia a todos!"
```

Comment: Um detalhe: a solução com `split` considera que a pontuação faz parte da palavra. Então se a frase for `"Vai lá!!!"`, ela considera que `lá!!!` é a maior "palavra". Já a solução com regex considera números também, então se a frase for `vai 1234`, ela considera que `1234` é a maior "palavra". Sem contar que `\w` também considera o caractere `_`, então `___` também é considerada uma palavra. E nenhum dos casos trata palavras compostas ("beija-flor" é uma única palavra). Enfim, as respostas podem estar certas ou não, dependendo da definição de "palavra"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe várias formas de fazer isso, veja abaixo alguns exemplos:

```js
//String que será avaliada
let string = "Bom dia a todos!";

//Declaro a maior string vazia
let big = "";

//Transformo a string em uma lista com o split, separando por espaços em branco
string.split(" ").forEach(word => {
  if (word.trim().length > big.length) {
    big = word.trim();
  }
});

console.log(big);

//Também transformo a string em uma lista com o split, mas utilizo do reduce para retornar a maior palavra
let bigger = string.split(" ").reduce( (acumulador, valorCorrente) => {
  if (acumulador.length < valorCorrente.trim().length) {
    return valorCorrente.trim();
  }

  return acumulador;
}, "");

console.log(bigger);

//Novamente o split, mas dessa fez é efetuado um for simples
let palavras = string.split(" ");
let bigFor = "";

for (word of palavras) {
  if (word.trim().length > bigFor.length) {
    bigFor = word.trim();
  }
}

console.log(bigFor);
```

**Explicação:** Utilizando o `split` na string, conseguimos gerar uma lista, utilizamos o espaço como base para isso. Com a lista em mãos, temos diversas formas de verificar qual é a maior string, para isso utilizamos a propriedade `length` da string. Existem três exemplos, um efetuando um `forEach` na lista, outro utilizando do `reduce` e por fim um loop bem simples.

---

> Referências:
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Um detalhe: vc considera que a pontuação faz parte da palavra. Então se a frase for `"Vai lá!!!"`, a maior "palavra" será `lá!!!`. Claro que faltou a pergunta definir melhor o que quer (se são só palavras do ponto de vista da gramática, ou "qualquer coisa que não seja espaço"), mas de qualquer forma, é um ponto de atenção :-)

Answer (score 1):

A logica utilizada a baixo separa as palavras utilizando o `split` e salvando em um array e um forEach percorrendo o array e fazendo a verificação da quantidade de letras em cada posição do `arrayStr`

```js
function maiorPalavra(string) {
    var arrayStr = string.split(" ");
    var maior = 0;
    var palavra = null;
    arrayStr.forEach(function(str) {
        if (maior < str.length) {
            maior = str.length;
            palavra = str;
        }
    });
    return palavra;
}
console.log(maiorPalavra("bom dia a todos"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Mais uma maneira usando regex, ordenando pelo tamanho das palavras e pegando o primeiro elemento.

```js
const string = "Bom dia a todos!";

const result = string
  .match(/\w+/g)
  .sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length)[0];
  
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Isso é incrível +1.

Comment: Um detalhe é que `\w` também considera números e o caractere `_`, então se a frase for `vai 1234`, o número `1234` será considerado a maior "palavra", e coisas como `___`, `a2` e `_123_` também serão consideradas palavras. Claro que faltou a pergunta definir melhor o que é uma palavra, mas de qualquer forma, é um ponto de atenção :-)